# Are the question limits permanent?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

When I first got an account in Stack overflow, I posted two questions which got down-voted. Then, I got a question limit, and I assumed it would go away with gaining reputation. It did not. Are they permanent?

Comment: Your current temporary rate limit ends on 2019-01-17 18:12:21Z. If you hit the rate limit too many times from low-quality posts you may encounter a permanent [post ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: @SamuelLiew - How many is "too many" to merit a permanent post ban?

Comment: @lit I recall that the algorithm is confidential, to avoid gaming with the limits.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Shouldn't this be an answer rather than a comment?